# How to set custom attribute as a non system attribute

Tags: magento

In a custom magento script, i have the following snippet of code to create attributes

```
$attributeName  = 'test'; // Name of the attribute
$attributeCode1 = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", 'test')); // Code of the attribute
$attributeCode  =  strlen($attributeCode1,0,30);// Code of the attribute
$attributeGroup = 'General';          // Group to add the attribute to
$attributeSetIds = array(4);          // Array with attribute set ID's to add this attribute to. (ID:4 is the Default Attribute Set)

// Configuration:
$data = array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',       // Attribute type
    'input'     => 'text',          // Input type
    'global'    => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,    // Attribute scope
    'required'  => false,           // Is this attribute required?
    'user_defined' => false,
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'unique' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    // Filled from above:
    'label' => $attributeName
);
// Create attribute:

$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup'); 
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode, $data);

// Add the attribute to the proper sets/groups:
foreach($attributeSetIds as $attributeSetId)
{
    $installer->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSetId, $attributeGroup, $attributeCode);
}
$installer->endSetup();
```

But however when they are created they are all system attributes and they are all required also.
is there something i am missing?